# Touchpad Detecting Input Less Than 3mm From Surface Problem

Tags: mouse, touchpad, input

Today I installed Linux Mint on an Inspiron N5050 laptop I received today, and am having a strange problem. I hope someone here can maybe suggest a solution.

The touchpad is registering mouse/touch events when my finger is less than 3mm from the surface of the touchpad. This leads to a very annoying problem where the cursor invariably moves a significant distance on screen whenever I lift a finger from the touchpad.

I am quite sure the problem could be corrected if the touchpad only registered mouse/touch events when my finger is actually in physical contact with the touchpad, not within a few millimeters of its surface.

I've updated my BIOS to the latest and the problem persists. Do any of you have recommendations as to what else I might try?

Thank you.

Comment: It is setable in X. Slight help in [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483707/14-04-touchpad-is-too-sensitive).

Comment: A touchpad (or capacitive touch panel) can't sense physical contact. It detects the change in capacitive coupling caused by nearby objects like your finger. Typically, the sensitivity can be adjusted to meet different requirements. This is done by the driver code setting some registers in the touch driver IC.

Now there are many different touch driver ICs, different drivers for them and even different methods how to configure it (device tree, configuration file in `/etc`, some `/sys/class/inputdevices/touch/whatever/sensitivity` pseudo file, a calibration utility etc.